# QuantLib starter guide

Tags: c++, finance, quantlib

Is there a good starter document on quantlib (http://quantlib.org)? The examples are not well documented, and the help does not give that much insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well there are

- hundreds of unit tests,
- a dozen or more examples
- over 1000 pages of Doxygen-generated documentation
- several [introductory book chapters on the design](http://implementingquantlib.com/) drafted by Luigi (lead developer)

All this is complicated because the topic is complicated.  The *No Free Lunch* theorem seems to hold for code too ;-)

Thanks for adding the quantlib tag. We should have some more questions here.

Answer (score 3):

Quantlib creators are pretty active on the [Wilmott forum](http://wilmott.com/index.cfm?NoCookies=Yes&forumid=1), so if you ask a concrete question there, they are likely to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [QuantCorner](http://quantcorner.wordpress.com). I posted a couple of example codes relying on QL, there.